# Rebuild Old Pretty-Slugs

Tags: mysql, wordpress, slug

I have a WordPress 3.1.3 site that was hacked, so I decided to rebuild it from scratch with 3.3.1. I will manually port the old posts. The problem is that the prior pretty-URLs had a year/mongth/ format, and now the new site is incapable of producing the "year/month" that my older posts had.

In other words, when I'm done, all inbound links will be broken. How can I "hack" the new site, so that the year/month portion of the slug reflects some time far in the past (two years ago, etc)?

I figure I have to visit a table in my database, but which one? What column?

Comment: Would you consider going with 301 redirects in an .htaccess file?  You could add a rule that 301 redirects any of your old year/month URLs to match the new slug you've chosen for posts.

Comment: Pat: yes, I am considering that.  But I'd like to reproduce the slug internally if possible, before I "resort" to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the new site incapable of the same permalink structure? Why not import the old database?

Try the plugin [WordPress › Redirection « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/); import a CSV of your old and new slugs if possible.

Comment: The whole issue has now become moot.  I just noticed that 3.3.1 uses the "publish date" to construct the full URL, including the year/month. Version 3.1.3 did not behave that way.  Anyway, I now consider this issue closed.